# Prevent Illegal Argument Exception for Objects within Arrays in ElasticSearch

Tags: arrays, object, elasticsearch

I try to import JSON objects into ElasticSearch DB.
The fix should prevent the following error:

```
"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [state.config.assertions.target] cannot be changed from type [text] to [long]"},"status":400
```

The array of objects causing the problems looks like this:

```
"assertions": [
          {
            "operator": "lessThan",
            "type": "responseTime",
            "target": 3000
          },
          {
            "operator": "is",
            "type": "statusCode",
            "target": 200
          },
          {
            "operator": "is",
            "property": "content-type",
            "type": "header",
            "target": "text/html"
          }
        ]
```

The mapping expects type "long" after two objects and throws the error because of the "text" it receives with the third object.

Making the object "nested" will cause the same error:

```
      "assertions": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
```

This solution removes the error, but it is only fixing the problem instead of preventing it.

```
"assertions": {
                "properties": {
                  "operator": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "target": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
```

Mapping should stay enabled for querying.

The problem is with objects within arrays that have unexpected value types for the same keys.
How can I set parameters for mapping to accept other value types than expected?
How can I prevent these errors instead of fixing them?

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent this through elasticsearch mapping, each field in elasticsearch can have only one [data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) and will give you an exception if you try to store anything that does not match the data type in the mapping, like the one you got.

You can't have a field that stores a `numeric` value for one document and a `keyword` value for other.

If you have a field that can have different data types as the value, such as numbers, booleans and words, you should map this field as `keyword`, as you did, if you do not create a mapping for the field before indexing, elasticsearch will create the mapping the first time it receives a document with the field and will use that value to create the mapping.

What you can do to at least index part of the document is to set the [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed) option to true, this way if you have a mapping exception for a field, only this field will be reject, not the entire document.